# Simple App with two views and memory Leaks. What is the problem?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, memory-leaks

I have a simple App with two Views in SwiftUI and there is a Memory Leak, but I don’t know where:

**MAIN**

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

@main
struct TravelAppApp: App {
    @State var isLoggedIn: Bool = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "Login") == nil ? false : true
        
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if isLoggedIn {
                ContentView(isLoggedIn: $isLoggedIn)
                    .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
            } else {
                LoginView(isLoggedIn: $isLoggedIn)
                    .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

**Content View**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var isLoggedIn: Bool
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, world!")
            Button {
                isLoggedIn = false
            } label: {
                Text("Log in")
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

**Login View**

```
import SwiftUI

struct LoginView: View {
    @Binding var isLoggedIn: Bool
    
    @State var username = ""
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            Image("Login")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .frame(width: proxy.size.width)
                    .blur(radius: 6)
                    .overlay {
                            TextField(text: $username) {
                                Text(username)
                            }
                            Button {
                                isLoggedIn = true
                            } label: {
                                Text("Log in")
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(30)
                }
        }
        
    }
}
```

If I tap on "Log In" in the LoginView and then tap on "Log In" in the ContentView, I switch between these two views. However, if I repeat this process multiple times, the memory usage increases.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tu8v.png)
And I noticed that the Malloc Blocks are increasing while I am using the app, as mentioned above. What could be the issue with the memory usage?"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZwFp.png)

I checked does the ARC working. But it does.
I checked my code with ChatGPT, but it said nothing about this issue.
I have a bigger App with the same issue and  have created this small app to understand how does it work, but understand nothing.

Comment: Probably not related to the memory issue but why not use the AppStorage property wrapper instead of State/Binding?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, yeah, I'll try, thank you. And I think that the memory is increasing because of the build scheme. Could it be that Xcode is recording some data, such as the memory graph?